# Creating a Custom Post as a repository for theme constants

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a custom post with different custom fields so that if a download document used in many pages changes the user can come here to update the name.
In other words, if the document sitting in www.web.com/uploads/catalog2012.pdf is upgraded to catalog2013.pdf, the user would be able to change the document name here.

Thanks in Advance,

Mauro

Answer (score 1):

Post meta data are for posts only. You should not create a new post type to use custom options.

There is a dedicated [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) for that use case. [Create an options page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) and let the user update the option there.